# UWP app on Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, raspbian-jessie, windows-iot

I'm part-way through making a headed UWP app for my Raspberry Pi 3, which is running Windows IoT Core. I would like to switch to it running Raspbian Jessie, so that I can use the RasPi cam, but I don't know if this is possible.

Is it possible to run UWP apps on Raspbian Jessie, or failing that, is it possible to design GUIs with XAML for Raspbian? I looked into alternatives, but I would prefer to remain with XAML.

Comment: Sounds a little complicated. There's the likes of GTK+ for Mono, but it's not XAML based. If it were me, I'd be investigating either shifting to a web-based interface and ditching C# in favour of Python, *or* abandoning the Pi camera board and making do with something USB that you can interface with from Win IoT.

Comment: That is a very interesting question. I think you can design XAML Forms that will run on a Linux desktop with Mono installed. I would have thought that UWP also run under mono but .. I never even thought of that. They are meant to run on other devices like iOS and Android...

Comment: Seems like I'll need to start again then - good thing I didn't finish it! I did look into using Python as a back-end, but I found the lack of {}s rather disturbing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am sorry to say that UWP will not run on anything but Windows 10.(It is universal for any Windows 10 device... not truly a universal OS solution :( ) The portability was intended for Windows 10 devices only. It depends on the Windows Runtime (WinRT) which the API is only available on Windows 10 at the moment.

But there is this project called [C#/XAML for HTML 5](http://www.cshtml5.com/)  which build HTML based on XAML. That way you could use Cordova to deploy apps to *nix Operating Systems.

You can also explore the Xamarim SDK in VS2015 - I think they offer their own XAML designer for cross platform applications.

Comment: Thanks. I thought as much, but I hoped there was a way. I think I'll look into Xamarin.

Comment: Yea.. that is a real bummer about UWP. For some reason I had thought I could use it on *nix systems too. sigh...

Comment: I just installed Xamrin and I can see a few new project types. One in particular is Cross-Platform and it has Xamarin.Forms in there. That will use the X API on the OS, rendering native forms for that OS but you only develop it once. THis is where I got confused with UWP and Xamarin Universal (but universal is something else in Xamarin now too, basically aligning with Windows Universal, you can have universal Android or iOS apps, only for that platform) I think the Cross Platform Forms will work well... but its not XAML

Comment: (Just the usual M$: "it will run on all platoforms" = "It will run on all devices that run Windos 10"... It's not the first time they do this.)